# Why is it true that $(a_1 \ a_2 \dots a_r) = (a_1 \ a_r)(a_1 \ a_{r-1})\dots(a_1 \ a_3)(a_1 \ a_2)$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In the theory of permutation, a $r$-cycle $(a_1 a_2...a_r)$ is defined in the following way:

> Start from $a_i$, a permutation function $f$ sends $a_i$ to $a_{i+1}$. When $i=r, a_i \text{ will be sent to }a_1$.

So if I start from $a_1$, it will be sent to $a_2$, which will be sent to $a_3$, and so on.

My question is, why is it true that $(a_1 a_2 \dots a_r) = (a_1 a_r)(a_1 a_{r-1})\dots(a_1 a_3)(a_1 a_2)$?

Comment: I somehow feel that this question has been altered beyond recognition, which makes older answer look inadequate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_r) = (a_1, a_r)(a_1, a_{r-1})\dots(a_1, a_3)(a_1, a_2) $$

Comment: Assume this is true, then wouldn't $a_1$ be directed to $a_2$ as well as $a_3,...,a_r$?

Comment: Nope. By composition, performing the transpositions from right to left, $a_1 \mapsto a_2$ so $a_2$ is the new $a_1$ and that gets mapped to $a_3$ and so on, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ (a_1\,a_2\,\ldots\, a_n)(a_n\,a_{n+1})=(a_1\,a_2\,\ldots\,a_n\,a_{n+1})$$

Answer (score 1):

Try to see it for a little $r$ like $3$. In this case you have $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(a_1,a_3)(a_1,a_2)$. A permutation of $r$ elements in general is a bijection of the set $\{1,...,r\}$ to itself. In our particular the permutation $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is a function such that $a_i\longmapsto a_{i+1}$ and $a_3\longmapsto a_1$. So

$$
a_1\longmapsto a_2\\
a_2\longmapsto a_3\\
a_3\longmapsto a_1.
$$

Now what happens if we compose the following permutations $(a_1,a_3)(a_1,a_2)$?

$$
a_1\longmapsto a_2\longmapsto a_2\\
a_2\longmapsto a_1\longmapsto a_3\\
a_3\longmapsto a_3\longmapsto a_1
$$

so they are the same function.

In general the only cycle that moves $a_i$ with $i>1$ is $(a_1,a_i)$, otherwise it remain fixed by other cycles. Every cycle change the position of $a_1$ with $a_i$ and finally shift back $a_1$ to the latest position ($i.e.$ on the right). So the composition clearly is $(a_2\dots a_1)$.